# Xamarin The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, remote-server

I going to login xamarin account in VS 2017
what is this an error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it is generally no longer necessary to use the old Xamarin account login, so it is recommended to move away from that old login mechanism as soon as you can.

If you are attempting to log in to use the Xamarin Component Store, note that it is recommended to migrate to corresponding NuGet packages at this time: https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/.

If you are logging in to use Xamarin features, note that starting with the [Xamarin versions released in March 2016](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/), you no longer need to log in to a Xamarin account to use Xamarin features. Visual Studio will automatically provide Xamarin features based on your Visual Studio subscription level.

If you have a special case where those 2 pieces of information don't resolve the issue, you can reach out via a [support incident](https://www.xamarin.com/support) for further assistance.